# Не работает переход по ссылкам на другие страницы по клику ЛКМ, только по СКМ, как исправить?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, javascript-events

Не работает переход c главной страницы на другие по клику ЛКМ, только по СКМ (открыть в новой вкладки) в WordPress. Причём на остальных страницах всё работает нормально, только лишь на главной такой феномен. Сайт vaerox.ru , шаблон Monolit. Как исправить? Буду очень благодарен.

Причину уже выяснил: на главной странице для тега, a навешано 3 обработчика, на внутренних 2. Если удалить "лишний" обработчик и кликнуть на пункте меню, то все работает.

Лишний обработчик обозначен на скрине:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос такой - как можно удалить этот ненужный обработчик, пробовал закомментировать код его код в jquery, где он и находится, баг пропадает, но тогда слетает вообще все функции страницы. Как решить этот феномен?

Функция, вызывающая баг:

```js
proxy: function (a, b) { var c, e, f; return "string" == typeof b && (c = a[b], b = a, a = c), n.isFunction(a) ? (e = d.call(arguments, 2), f = function () { return a.apply(b || this, e.concat(d.call(arguments))) }, f.guid = a.guid = a.guid || n.guid++, f) : void 0 },
```

Функция, которая создаёт баг, находится в Jquery.js, версии jquery менял, всегда одно и тоже, обработчик "а" мешает переходу по ссылкам.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что автор удалил свой такой же вопрос (а там были комментарии), и создал дубликат.

Comment: Здесь так не делают. Не надо удалять вопрос (где вам в комментариях указали на неправильное его оформление) и создавать новый.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках страницы Вордпресс сменил шаблон страницы с Home Landing Page на Home Page и ошибка пропала. Если в вас тоже возникнет такая проблема, пробуйте! Авось и решится, как решилось это у меня :)